# Pandas Convert 'NA' to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I just picked up Pandas to do with some data analysis work in my biology research. Turns out one of the proteins I'm analyzing is called 'NA'.

I have a matrix with pairwise 'HA, M1, M2, NA, NP...' on the column headers, and the same as "row headers" (for the biologists who might read this, I'm working with influenza).

When I import the data into Pandas directly from a CSV file, it reads the "row headers" as 'HA, M1, M2...' and then NA gets read as NaN. Is there any way to stop this? The column headers are fine - 'HA, M1, M2, NA, NP etc...'

Comment: for the stupid hack solution, you can do search/replace in the csv and rename `NA` to something like `NA_safe`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turn off NaN detection this way: `pd.read_csv(filename, keep_default_na=False)`

I originally suggested `na_filter=False`, which gets the job done. But, if I understand Jeff's comments below, this is a cleaner solution.

Example:

```
In [1]: pd.read_csv('test')
Out[1]:[4]: pd.read_csv('test', keep_default_na=False)
Out[4]:1   2
2   3
```

Comment: perhaps also worth mentioning `na_values` :)

Comment: Yes. Speaking of, it seems odd to me that neither ``na_values=None`` (the default) nor ``na_values=[]`` suppresses NaN detection in this case.

Comment: FYI na_filter is a different type of option, meant to 'turn off' nan detection entirely, whereas na_values allows new/different values to be detected, and to complicate things, keep_na_filter allows you to NOT use the default na values...! maybe need an example in the docs / cookbook!

Comment: also to note, turning off nan detection results in the dtype of the column (if it say has mixed string/ints) to be ``object``, not in general a good thing, you DO want to convert to base types whenever possible for efficiency

Comment: Jeff, is ``keep_na_filter`` a thing? I can't find it in the read_csv docs, but I think I know what you meant. If my revised answer is not optimal, I will happily accept edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this issue--I specified a str converter for the column instead, so I could keep na elsewhere: 
`pd.read_csv(... , converters={ "file name": str, "company name": str})`

Comment: This will help in avoiding NA to nan in one specific column.