# pandas.read_csv named argument na_values default values

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas automatically converts certain values to `NaN` when importing data from csv, Excel, sql, etc (e.g. methods in `pandas.io.parsers`).

My question is, what are these default values?

I've noticed that the string `"NA"` gets automatically converted. As [others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596188/pandas-convert-na-to-nan), one can disable this automatic conversion by passing `keep_default_na=False` when calling the function that imports the data (e.g. pandas.io.parsers.read_csv).

That said, I do not know which values other than `"NA"` are automatically converted. In [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), all I can find is the following description for the `keep_default_na` argument:

> keep_default_na : bool, default True
>   If na_values are specified and keep_default_na is False the default NaN values are overridden, otherwise they’re appended to

What I'd like to know is, what are the aforementioned 'default NaN values'?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff provided a link almost a year ago, but since following links is cumbersome, I moved the information here.

```
['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A','N/A', 'NA', '#NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan']
```

Source: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values

## HOWEVER

This list is not complete.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

sio = StringIO()
sio.write('"foo","bar"\n"1",""\n"NA","4"')
sio.seek(0)
pd.read_csv(sio, sep=",", quotechar='"')
   foo  bar
0    1  NaN
1  NaN    4
```

Note how the empty string was not a part of the list, but it still gets parsed as NaN by default?

```
pd.read_csv(sio, sep=",", quotechar='"',
            keep_default_na=False,
            na_values=['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND',
                       '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A','N/A', '#NA', 'NA'
                       'NULL', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan'])

  foo bar
0   1    
1 NaN   4
```

If this list would be the default, these two commands *should* produce the exact same result.

They don't.

If you want to reproduce the default behaviour of `pandas.read_csv`, this is the list you need:

```
['', '-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A','N/A', 'NA', '#NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan']
```

Pandas version for reference:

```
pd.__version__
'0.15.2'
```

Bug ticket with pandas:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10700

## Update

This is fixed in pandas 0.17

Comment: If you think the list is not complete, please open an issue on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues (or a PR with a doc change?)

Comment: Good catch, mate. Thanks for the detailed answer!