# Need help understanding index_col in read_excel (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file where the first column is "ID" and the items are of the form IDXXX.

This code

```
s = pd.read_excel('error4.xlsx', keep_default_na = False, index_col = 0)
```

Comes up with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#324>", line 1, in <module>
    shit = pd.read_excel('error4.xlsx', keep_default_na = False, index_col = 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 438, in _parse_excel
    if not com.is_list_like(header):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 740, in read
    if fallback_reason:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1601, in read
    self._make_reader(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 910, in _make_index
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1002, in _agg_index
    % ','.join([str(x) for x in self.header])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'set'
```

I have tried reading the documentation but I don't get it. It works fine if I remove `index_col = 0`. `index_col = 'ID'` doesn't work either.

Comment: It's strange indeed. When you use keep_default_na and index_col together, it raises the error. A workaround: `pd.read_excel('error4.xlsx', keep_default_na = False).set_index('ID')`

Comment: It even happens with `read_csv`, I think it'a bug you should report it.

Comment: It is happening since he has only one column, this does not happen with multiple columns. This behaviour is expected it is not a bug. See my answer below

Comment: I have more than one column (637 x 22)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is coming due to the option:

```
keep_default_na = False
```

According to the documentation:

```
na_values : str or list-like or dict, default None
Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’.

keep_default_na : bool, default True
If na_values are specified and keep_default_na is False the default NaN values are overridden, otherwise they’re appended to.
```

So if you have no specified any new values that are to be converted to NaN why do you need this option

## EDIT

If you have a file with a single column,say i have a file output2.csv with a single column :

```
  cmfa
-0.0019
-0.0018
-0.0033
```

if you use the following command `

```
s = pd.read_csv('output2.csv',keep_default_na = False,index_col=0)
```

it will throw out an error saying `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'set'`

Because the dataset does not have any columns to operate on and retain NaN values as you are trying with the keep_default_na statement. It just has an index determined by your column.

However the following works as expected
`s = pd.read_csv('output2.csv',index_col=0)`

and gives an output (Note there are no columns)

```
print s
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [-0.0019, -0.0018, -0.0033]
```

If you do want to keep an `keep_default_na=False` statement then you have to do away with `index_col=0` option since the statement needs some values to operate on and let the dataframe have the default indexing of 0,1,2,3 etc.

## EDIT2

It seems pandas does not work when you club the `index_col` and `keep_default_na = False` statement, that being said as per the documentation it also does not expect the `keep_default_na = False` to be specified without specifying `na_values`

So use the following in your case :

```
s = pd.read_csv('output.csv',na_values=[],keep_default_na = False,index_col=0)
```

If you are not specifying `na_values`, `keep_default_na=False` works standalone if `index_col = None or False` else it will throw out an error for any other value of `index_col`. So a good programming practice is to use the `na_values` option in such cases, although I do agree there should be better error handling in pandas regarding this.

Comment: That's for the NULL values in the file that I don't want converted to NaN. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596188/pandas-convert-na-to-nan) for reference. `s = pd.read_excel('error4.xlsx', keep_default_na = False)` works fine without any errors.

Comment: Do you only have one column in your excel file?

Comment: I have more than one column (around 20)

Comment: See EDIT2 of the answer please, you need to specify `na_values=[]` as well for your code to work