# Reproducing Excel average and rounding in Python

Tags: python, pandas, average, rounding

I read several questions about rounding in Python, but cannot reproduce my Excel results.

I have a rows with numbers and `NA`s too:

**Reprex via print(reprex.to_dict())**

```
{'Column 1': {0: 0}, 'Column 2': {0: 0}, 'Column 3': {0: 95}, 'Column 4': {0: 2}, 'Column 5': {0: 2}, 'Column 6': {0: 0}, 'Column 7': {0: 83}, 'Column 8': {0: 95}, 'Column 9': {0: 100}, 'Column 10': {0: 90}, 'Column 11': {0: 7}, 'Column 12': {0: 0}, 'Column 13': {0: 98}, 'Column 14': {0: 97}, 'Column 15': {0: 14}, 'Column 16': {0: 1}, 'Column 17': {0: 0}, 'Column 18': {0: 3}, 'Column 19': {0: 7}, 'Column 20': {0: 9}, 'Column 21': {0: 5}, 'Column 22': {0: 6}, 'Column 23': {0: 10}, 'Column 24': {0: 4}, 'Column 25': {0: 7}, 'Column 26': {0: 5}, 'Column 27': {0: 13}, 'Column 28': {0: 3}, 'Column 29': {0: 5}, 'Column 30': {0: 0}, 'Column 31': {0: 97}, 'Column 32': {0: 96}, 'Column 33': {0: 97}, 'Column 34': {0: 98}, 'Column 35': {0: 97}, 'Column 36': {0: 100}, 'Column 37': {0: 97}, 'Column 38': {0: 97}, 'Column 39': {0: 97}, 'Column 40': {0: 91}, 'Column 41': {0: 97}, 'Column 42': {0: 5}, 'Column 43': {0: 10}, 'Column 44': {0: nan}, 'Column 45': {0: 10}, 'Column 46': {0: 7}, 'Column 47': {0: 8}, 'Column 48': {0: 6}, 'Column 49': {0: 14}, 'Column 50': {0: 22}, 'Column 51': {0: 17}, 'Column 52': {0: 8}, 'Column 53': {0: 21}, 'Column 54': {0: 19}, 'Column 55': {0: 20}, 'Column 56': {0: 18}, 'Column 57': {0: 15}, 'Column 58': {0: 19}}
```

Excel function `Average()` gives me `35.85964912`, rounds to `36`.

I checked if I subset columns properly several times.

When I do

```
cols = df.iloc[: , 133:191]
df['score'] = cols.mean(axis = 1)
```

Python gives me the average of `37.905660`.

As a result, rounding in Excel gives me `38`, using

```
df = df.round({'Overall_mean_procedure_PB_score': 0})
```

2 is a huge difference. Maybe `NA` creates a problem here.

How to do properly such calculations, following the Excel?

Comment: How does the dataframe looks like? Does the NA in excel translate to NaN? Pandas mean will work with NaN's - See documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: @BigBen, added, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: @HenrikBo, added the exact example

Comment: @BigBen, greta, helpful, how did you write the code for this? Something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduce the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    "Column 1": {0: 0},
    "Column 2": {0: 0},
    "Column 3": {0: 95},
    "Column 4": {0: 2},
    "Column 5": {0: 2},
    "Column 6": {0: 0},
    "Column 7": {0: 83},
    "Column 8": {0: 95},
    "Column 9": {0: 100},
    "Column 10": {0: 90},
    "Column 11": {0: 7},
    "Column 12": {0: 0},
    "Column 13": {0: 98},
    "Column 14": {0: 97},
    "Column 15": {0: 14},
    "Column 16": {0: 1},
    "Column 17": {0: 0},
    "Column 18": {0: 3},
    "Column 19": {0: 7},
    "Column 20": {0: 9},
    "Column 21": {0: 5},
    "Column 22": {0: 6},
    "Column 23": {0: 10},
    "Column 24": {0: 4},
    "Column 25": {0: 7},
    "Column 26": {0: 5},
    "Column 27": {0: 13},
    "Column 28": {0: 3},
    "Column 29": {0: 5},
    "Column 30": {0: 0},
    "Column 31": {0: 97},
    "Column 32": {0: 96},
    "Column 33": {0: 97},
    "Column 34": {0: 98},
    "Column 35": {0: 97},
    "Column 36": {0: 100},
    "Column 37": {0: 97},
    "Column 38": {0: 97},
    "Column 39": {0: 97},
    "Column 40": {0: 91},
    "Column 41": {0: 97},
    "Column 42": {0: 5},
    "Column 43": {0: 10},
    "Column 44": {0: np.nan},
    "Column 45": {0: 10},
    "Column 46": {0: 7},
    "Column 47": {0: 8},
    "Column 48": {0: 6},
    "Column 49": {0: 14},
    "Column 50": {0: 22},
    "Column 51": {0: 17},
    "Column 52": {0: 8},
    "Column 53": {0: 21},
    "Column 54": {0: 19},
    "Column 55": {0: 20},
    "Column 56": {0: 18},
    "Column 57": {0: 15},
    "Column 58": {0: 19},
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

df.mean()
```

Output:

```
0    35.859649
dtype: float64
```

Seems to work well. I think the NA is the problem. Translate it to a python NaN type.

Comment: Looking into this, thanks. Any tip how to convert all NA into NaN in the dataframe?

Comment: `df = df.replace({pd.NA: np.nan})` is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596188/pandas-convert-na-to-nan

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Henrik Bo, I resolved. I messed up with `NaN` and `NA` in the dataframe.

When I did

```
# Replace all outlier values with np.NaN
df = df.replace(outlier_value, np.NaN)
```

the calculation became correct.